# how can I un-groupby my dataframe in pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataset like this:

| project id | phase 1 | phase 2 | phase 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 112 | 29 | 157 | 213 |
| 113 | 36 | 121 | 23 |

how can I get it transformed to a dataset like this:

| project id | phase | days |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 112 | 1 | 29 |
| 112 | 2 | 157 |
| 112 | 3 | 213 |
| 112 | cumulative | 399 |
| 113 | 1 | 36 |
| 113 | 2 | 121 |
| 113 | 3 | 23 |
| 113 | cumulative | 180 |

thanks!

Comment: Check out  `.melt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is another way to do it

calculate the cumulative by row, then melt it. finally replacing out the text phase

```
df['cumulative'] = df[['phase1','phase2','phase3']].sum(axis=1)
df=df.melt(id_vars='projectid', var_name='phase', value_name='days').sort_values('projectid')
df['phase'] = df['phase'].replace(r'phase','', regex=True)
df
```

```
    projectid   phase   days
0   112             1   29
2   112             2   157
4   112             3   213
6   112     cumulative  399
1   113             1   36
3   113             2   121
5   113             3   23
7   113     cumulative  180
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
df = df.set_index("project id")
df = (
    df.assign(cumulative=df.sum(axis=1))
    .stack()
    .to_frame(name="days")
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={"level_1": "phase"})
)
df["phase"] = df["phase"].str.replace("phase ", "")
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   project id       phase  days
0         112           1    29
1         112           2   157
2         112           3   213
3         112  cumulative   399
4         113           1    36
5         113           2   121
6         113           3    23
7         113  cumulative   180
```